# ng-reapeat row data to column angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.value = {"id":"1", "future_date1" : "0000-00-00", "future_date2" : "0000-00-00","future_date3" : "2018-10-10","future_date4" : "2018-11-11","future_date5" : "2018-12-12", "fut_amt1" : "", "fut_amt2" : "0", "fut_amt3" : "16", "fut_amt4" : "20","fut_amt5" : "15"}
```

It should be in table

How can we solve with using ng-repeat or how this possible in easy way angularjs

```
Date        Amt
2018-10-10  16
2018-11-11  20
2018-12-12  15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to transform your object into an array first in your controller and then can simply use **ng-repeat** on that. Try following.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = {"id":"1", "future_date1" : "0000-00-00", "future_date2" : "0000-00-00","future_date3" : "2018-10-10","future_date4" : "2018-11-11","future_date5" : "2018-12-12", "fut_amt1" : "", "fut_amt2" : "0", "fut_amt3" : "16", "fut_amt4" : "20","fut_amt5" : "15"};
  $scope.updatedValue = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= (Object.keys($scope.value).length-1)/2; i++) {
    if($scope.value["future_date"+i] !== '0000-00-00') 
    $scope.updatedValue.push({
      "date" : $scope.value["future_date"+i],
      "amt" : $scope.value["fut_amt"+i]
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr><td>Date</td><td>Amt</td></tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="val in updatedValue"><td>{{val.date}}</td><td>{{val.amt}}</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to iterate through your object and display Date and Amt values.

JS:

```
$scope.value = {"id":"1", "future_date1" : "0000-00-00", "future_date2" : "0000-00-00","future_date3" : "2018-10-10","future_date4" : "2018-11-11","future_date5" : "2018-12-12", "fut_amt1" : "", "fut_amt2" : "0", "fut_amt3" : "16", "fut_amt4" : "20","fut_amt5" : "15"}

$scope.length = Math.floor(Object.keys($scope.value).length / 2);

$scope.getLength = function(){
    return new Array($scope.length);
}

$scope.getValueByIndex = function(index){
    var key = Object.keys($scope.value)[index];
    value = $scope.value[key];
    return value;
}
```

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
          Date
        </td>
        <td>
          Amt
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in getLength() track by $index" ng-if="getValueByIndex($index + 1 + length) > 0">
        <td>
          {{getValueByIndex($index + 1)}}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{getValueByIndex($index + 1 + length)}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/CXll6S3EjlA3zWMU70jE?p=preview)**